# In app engine, can I call "get_or_insert" from inside a transaction?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In google app engine, can I call "get_or_insert" from inside a transaction?

The reason I ask is because I'm not sure if there is some conflict with having this run its own transaction inside an already running transaction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it depends on whether you are using NDB or the old db package.  Nick's answer applies to the old db package only.  In NDB, however, get_or_insert() joins the current transaction if there is one.  If called outside a transaction it creates its own transaction.  This matches the semantics of propagation=ALLOWED documented here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions#context_options

(Nick is right about the restrictions on the entity group when joining the existing transaction.)

Answer (score 2):

No. `get_or_insert` is syntactic sugar for a transactional function that fetches or inserts a record. You can implement it yourself trivially, but that will only work if the record you're operating on is in the same entity group as the rest of the entities in the current transaction, or if you have cross-group transactions enabled.